# UIPageViewController - load it with epub context

Tags: epub, uipageviewcontroller

I am writing kind of book reader (epub) in my iPad app and going to use UIPageViewController. I know how to read epub but my question which control I should use to display singe page (ViewCotroller). I was thinking about WebView but not sure how it is gonna fit the whole page. Will it truncate it so I should manage to display 'unfit' context on the next page or it will automatically scroll page context down which is weird in term of UX. What is the pattern? How you generate epub page @your ViewController in your readers? What kind of component needs to be used? Help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check this sample
    https://github.com/fedefrappi/AePubReader

Comment: thanks, Prasanna. There are lots of useful code in this project which I probably will be reuse but it doesn't use UIPageViewController.

Comment: Have you work on landscape mode,if you have means kindly help me